# How to know the used size out of maximum size of an array in c programming language?

Tags: c, data-structures

Suppose I declared an array of int type, like `int a[50]`. But, I used only 10 locations in that array, like `a[9] = 33;`. In that case, how another programmer would know how many locations I used out of my maximum of 50 locations?

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't provide some magic "used/unused" flag that you can use. If the array only contains useful information up to some index, then you need to keep track of that index separately and communicate it to whichever code it concerns. For example:

```
int a[50];
int unusedIndex = 0;

// ...

a[unusedIndex] = someValue;
unusedIndex++;
```

Note that the last two lines could be collapsed to `a[unusedIndex++] = someValue`, but I've written them separately for ease of understanding.

Comment: You also should keep track of the size `50` somewhere as you don't want to allow anything to write over the amount you have allocated.

Comment: Thank you, @Time. Max size could be found with sizeof(). But, used size perhaps couldn't be found implicitly as per your answare. Anyway, thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: @NewBegin 'Max size could be found with sizeof()', well, maybe.  Once you start passing arguments to functions, not so much:(

Comment: @NewBegin array parameters are treated as pointers when you pass them to functions, so `sizeof` will you give you only pointer size not array size.

Answer (score 1):

The language does not give us these clues, unfortunately arrays in C are second-class passengers and we don't have alternatives like C++ vectors, so many times we are forced to build an API around the array (embedding the array in a `struct`), in your case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int data[50];
    int maximum;
} t_array;

static void array_set_value(t_array *array, int index, int value)
{
    array->data[index] = value;
    if (index > array->maximum)
    {
        array->maximum = index;
    }
}

static int array_get_maximum(t_array *array)
{
    return array->maximum;
}

int main(void)
{
    t_array array = {0};

    array_set_value(&array, 3, 0);
    array_set_value(&array, 9, 1);
    array_set_value(&array, 4, 2);

    printf("maximum size: %d\n", array_get_maximum(&array));
    return 0;
}
```

And since you have made the effort, you can improve the API to avoid accessing outside of the bounds of the array:

```
static int array_set_value(t_array *array, int index, int value)
{
    if (index >= (int)(sizeof array->data / sizeof *array->data))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    array->data[index] = value;
    if (index > array->maximum)
    {
        array->maximum = index;
    }
    return index;
}

...

if (array_set_value(&array, 50, 42) < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Accessing out of bounds\n");
}
```

And with a little trick you can make that structure generic and reuse it for other types, ... but that's another story :)